# Multithread Quicksort using vectors

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, vector, quicksort

Wheneever i build my code in visual studio i get the following

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   C2672   'std::invoke': no matching overloaded function found    Quicksort   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\thr\xthread  238

and

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   C2893   Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type std::invoke(_Callable &&,_Types &&...)'    Quicksort   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\thr\xthread  238

Without threads the code works fine using recursion. Though i want to implement 2 threads to which will recursively call the quicksort. Each thread takes half the array, one left, one right.  Am I properly calling the threads?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

vector<int> quickSort(vector<int> &arr, int &start, int &end) {
    //Set starting left and right positions for the iteration to come
    int pos_left = start;
    int pos_right = end;
    int tmp;

//Set pivot value
    int pivot = arr[(start + end) / 2];

//The algorithm will run as long as the right position and the left 
//position don't pass each other. It will stop when they both reach the 
//same position
    while (pos_left <= pos_right) {

//Increments left position until value at position is greater than
//the pivot
    while (arr[pos_left] < pivot)
        pos_left++;

//Decrements right position until value at position is smaller than
//the pivot
    while (arr[pos_right] > pivot)
        pos_right--;

//Swaps value at left position with value at right position then
//increments left position and decrements right position
    if (pos_left <= pos_right) {
        tmp = arr[pos_left];
        arr[pos_left] = arr[pos_right];
        arr[pos_right] = tmp;
        pos_left++;
        pos_right--;
    }
}

//Initialize threads. First thread will sort the resulting left partition
//and second thread will sort the resulting right partition of the vector
thread first (quickSort,arr, start, pos_right);
thread second (quickSort, arr, pos_left, end);

//The first thread will run until the left partition is sorted
    if (start < pos_right)
        first.join();
//The second thread will run until the right partition is sorted
    if (pos_left < end)
        second.join();

    return arr;
}


int main() {
    vector<int> myVector;

//Read the file "array.txt" file onto a vector
ifstream file("array.txt");
if (file.is_open()) {
    int val;
    while (file >> val) {
        myVector.push_back(val);
    }
    myVector.erase(myVector.begin());
}
//Set position of first value in vector
int start = 0;
//Set position of last value in vector
int end = myVector.size() - 1;

//Call the sorting alogrithm which takes starting position and end position of
//last vector value.
vector<int> sorted = quickSort(myVector, start, end);

//Write the sorted vector onto a text file "sorted.txt"
ofstream myfile;
myfile.open("sorted.txt");
for (int i = 0; i < sorted.size(); i++) {
    myfile << sorted[i];
    myfile << endl;
}
myfile.close();
}
```

Comment: Make it `thread first (quickSort, arr, start, pos_right);`; and similarly other uses of `std::thread`. As written, you are calling the function and then trying to pass the result it returns to `thread`, which makes no sense.

Comment: Do you know what `thread first (quickSort(arr, start, pos_right));` does?

Comment: Not sure what [thread first (quickSort(arr, start, pos_right));]. It is my first time coding with threads. I tried your solution igor which you are right about. Unfortunately i still get the same error

Comment: No, you get a different error. Anyway, the correct incantation is `thread first (quickSort, ref(arr),  ref(start), ref(pos_right));` since the function takes its parameters by reference.

Comment: Ahh okay thank you very much :)